# Why table border has doubled thickness and wrong color?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Unfortunately I can't show you a simple reproducible example beacuse in Codepen the issue doesn't take place, but when I've added the code into my application, I have double pixel border that is not exactly red as specified by css (in my example it's #ccc but it's not that color when I use eye dropper, so I've used red to see the issue better).

[image: Screenshot of browser bug]

It looks like a browser bug, I've disabled all css that is on table cell and browser is doubled even that it should have 1px and be red. As you can see in screenshot it's not exactly `FF0000`. The application is boostrap based shiny R application with default shiny modal (created using bootstrap).

Any idea what may cause this issue, note that I don't use any Houdini code, so there is only single line:

```css
td, th {
     border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

It also happen in Incognito mode so it's not browser extension.

It works fine in Firefox, maybe it's issue with experimental font-size-adjust property.

*EDIT:*

I expect to look like it should according to any CSS rules. Here is codepen demo where there is the same table with 1 pixel border.

https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/GRjWdWj

And here is screenshot with red border (I using different OS to post this so no zoom):

[image: Screenshot how this should look]

*EDIT2:* I'm just asking if someone have the same issue and maybe know the solution, I know it would be hard to find the fix from the information I've provided, if you don't have the issue yourself. So my question is more if you know that this is a bug and maybe found a way to fix.

Comment: Awesome and not even single comment.

Comment: well, there are several issues with your question that you can fix: 1) the first paragraph is somewhat puzzling. Did you mean "Unfortunately I *can't* show you simple example beacuse it works on Codepen. When I've added the CSS below to my application I got double pixel border that is not exactly red as specified by css."? 2) What prevents you from linking Codepen right in that phrase or, even better, adding an SO snippet? 3) "It look*s* like browser bug" – tell us what browser do you use! Ok, you mentioned it in tags, but please don't expect a reader to lookup there [to be continued]

Comment: 4) you should probably focus on one question at a time: either doubled thickness or wrong color. I suggest the former, wrong color is more difficult to measure ("as you can see on screenshot" is not acceptable, jpeg can mutate colors); 5) showing a CSS rule without a selector (`border-bottom: 1px solid red;`) is looks a bit disrespectful ("go and look it up yourself") 6) one expects from you a [mcve], clear expected and actual behavior descriptioins, some attempts to research, but the current post is somewhat structureless. Please do your best to edit it. Best regards

Comment: @YakovL I've fixed first sentence, it's Google Chrome there is respective tag added. As you can see the border is on the table, and the only way to add border to table is on td,th cell, I can add `td` selector, if that would help you. I've written that I can't create minimal working example because the issue is in my big application. the codepen have the same code. it would take weeks to create reproducible example and it probably will answer my question and found a bug.

Comment: @YakovL it's single question because those two things are related to each other, the line is some how merged. one pixel in css become two blended pixels, so color and tickness was changed.

Comment: have you tried to use `border-collapse`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Comment: @YakovL yes I use border collapse otherwide I will have space between borders

Comment: can you at least create some kind of page snapshot from the app and host it somewhere to reproduce the issue? I'm afraid nobody will help by wild-guessing what could went wrong

Comment: @YakovL will try to create something on Monday when I will be a work, I don't have access  that app right now. That probably will also be required to report bug for Chromium.

Comment: yeah, but to get that bug fixed you'll need the reproducible example even more